# multiple jqgrid in one page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have two jqgrid in one page but my problem is when i clicked add button of first grid first row is coming in edit mode it's fine but when i clicked add button of 2nd grid edit mode coming in 2nd row of 2nd grisd instate of first row of 2nd grid any solution thanks in advance

```
 var grid1 = new JQGrid(Name: "ReceiptdetGrid", LoadUrl: "/Receipt/GetGridData",
     Columns: new List<JQGridColumn>() {  
            new JQGridColumn(Name: "Id",ColHeader: "Id", DataType: "string", IsSortable:false, IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Hidden:true, Width:"0%"),
            new JQGridColumn(Name: "Sno",ColHeader: "SNo.", DataType: "string", IsSortable:false, Width:"10%", IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Hidden:false),              
            new JQGridColumn(Name: "HeadName",ColHeader: "Head", DataType: "string", IsSortable:true, IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Width:"45%",IsEditable:true,EditType:"select",Items:(ViewData["headlist"] as List<SelectListItem>),OnChange:"SelectheadChange"),
           new JQGridColumn(Name: "Amount",ColHeader: " Amount", DataType: "string",EditType:"text", Width:"45%", IsSortable:false,OnKeyUp:"CalculateTotalAmmount",IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Hidden:false,IsEditable:true),
        }, IsPaging: true, PageSize: "8", EditUrl: "/Receipt/KeepGridData", DeleteUrl: "/Receipt/DeleteGridData", IsSortable: true, FooterRow: true, ShowEmptyRows: true, EditType: JQGridEditType.Inline, IsEdit: true, IsDelete: true, IsInsert: true, Width: "900", Height: "200");
            @grid1.GetHtml();                                         
        }
```

2nd jqgrid

```
 var grid2 = new JQGrid(Name: "instru", LoadUrl: "/Receipt/GetGridData",
     Columns: new List<JQGridColumn>() {  
            new JQGridColumn(Name: "Id1",ColHeader: "Id1", DataType: "string", IsSortable:false, IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Hidden:true, Width:"0%"),
            new JQGridColumn(Name: "type",ColHeader: "type", DataType: "string", IsSortable:false, Width:"10%", IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Hidden:false),              
            new JQGridColumn(Name: "HeadName",ColHeader: "Head", DataType: "string", IsSortable:true, IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Width:"45%",IsEditable:true,EditType:"select",Items:(ViewData["headlist"] as List<SelectListItem>),OnChange:"SelectheadChange"),
           new JQGridColumn(Name: "Amount",ColHeader: " Amount", DataType: "string",EditType:"text", Width:"45%", IsSortable:false,OnKeyUp:"CalculateTotalAmmount",IsFixed:true, IsResize: true,Hidden:false,IsEditable:true),
        }, IsPaging: true, PageSize: "8", EditUrl: "/Receipt/KeepGridData", DeleteUrl: "/Receipt/DeleteGridData", IsSortable: true, FooterRow: true, ShowEmptyRows: true, EditType: JQGridEditType.Inline, IsEdit: true, IsDelete: true, IsInsert: true, Width: "900", Height: "200");
            @grid2.GetHtml();                                         
        }
```

when i ckeck add button of 1st grid it come but when i click add button of 2nd grid it comes in 2nd row not i first row of 2nd grid thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are handling everything on the back end, but it looks like you're hitting the same URLs in both grids:

load:

```
LoadUrl: "/Receipt/GetGridData"
```

edit:

```
EditUrl: "/Receipt/KeepGridData"
```

delete:

```
DeleteUrl: "/Receipt/DeleteGridData"
```

So unless I'm mistaken, you've basically may have made two grids that use the same interface to their data.  Again, it really depends on how the back end pages are handling the load, edit, and delete requests coming from these two grids.